# Android - Finger paint a bitmap only in specific areas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have two images.
An image with a red rectangle, and image all white. I would like to paint with your finger on the white image only where the other image is the red rectangle.
The image with the red rectangle should not be visible.
How can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create bounds for each image, e.g. with a Rect set to the cords of each image (position & size). In the view where your overriding onDraw() in, set the onTouchListener to the view itself.

In onTouch() check the event.getX()/getY() is within the bounds of the white image. Then use whiteImage.setPixel() to set the individual pixels of the Bitmap image. Alternatively use Canvas.drawPoint() instead of manipulating white bitmap image itself.

In regards to not displaying the red rectangle... just don't draw it?

Edit:
To your comment about non square/rect shapes. I would still check for the touch event in the rect and then pass it to the image if it has hit the shape.

Within the shape (I'm assuming it is a bitmap) you would do Bitmap.getPixel(x, y) and see if it is == to Color.White, if it is.. change it to whatever colour!

Comment: You can find more on how to draw to an Android Canvas @ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#shape-drawable.

Comment: I do not know in advance that will shape the image may be a rectangle as a star or an irregular shape.

Comment: See my edit :) I've included how you would do it with irregular shapes. Keep using the rect to improve performance, you don't want pixel checking all the time. Simple bounds first, then pixel

Comment: for individual pixels is perfect. The problem comes when I'm drawing a path.